# Getting expection on running spring boot turbine stream

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-rabbit, turbine

```
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableTurbineStream
public class MonitoringApplication {
}
```

application.yml

```
eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    client:
        enabled: true
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: ${REGISTRY_URL:http://system:system@localhost:8761/eureka}

endpoints:
    restart:
        enabled: true
    shutdown:
        enabled: true 



2016-09-09 15:14:36.850  WARN 19348 --- [           main] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Failed to declare exchange: Exchange [name=springCloudHystrixStream, type=topic, durable=true, autoDelete=false, internal=false, arguments={}], continuing...

    org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:309)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:547)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:76)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1374)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1367)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareExchange(RabbitAdmin.java:156)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.declareExchange(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:493)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:227)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:103)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:179)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.ChannelBindingService.bindConsumer(ChannelBindingService.java:93)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.bindInputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:188)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:55)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.start(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1301)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:65)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:874)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at de.bingo.core.application.AbstractApplication.runApplicationInternal(AbstractApplication.java:60)
        at de.bingo.generator.application.GeneratorAbstractApplication.runApplication(GeneratorAbstractApplication.java:57)
        at de.bingo.monitoring.application.MonitoringApplication.main(MonitoringApplication.java:45)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:811)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:725)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:296)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

POm

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

It simply means you don't have RabbitMQ running; by default boot connects to  `localhost:5672`.